# Expand floated LI only on click not any other li

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

I have a list of questions that on a click has a hidden div of content toggle in and out. This works fine, however since my LI's are floated, when I open one of the LI's it pushes the content adjacent to it down.

On click, the content opens (gap)

```
    LI   |    LI
    LI   |    LI
    LI   |    LI
  content|   
  content|   
    LI   |    LI
```

What i want to happen (no gap)

```
    LI   |    LI
    LI   |    LI
    LI   |    LI
  content|    LI
  content|
    LI   |
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>Some stuff
        <ul class="subMain"><li>content content content</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Some stuff
        <ul class="subMain"><li>content content content</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Some stuff
        <ul class="subMain"><li>content content content</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Some stuff
        <ul class="subMain"><li>content content content</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.main { 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; padding: 10px 0; 
    width: 500px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main li { 
    width: 50%; height: auto;
    float: left; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.subMain { 
  margin: 0; padding: 0; display: none;  
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul.main li').click(function () {
   $(this).find('.subMain').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/S89Uv/2/

Do I have to place these LIs into columns?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this without putting them in separate columns.  The way floats work, is they will wrap and take up whatever space is available.  This is why you see the LI's that were on the left move to the right when you expand an item above them.  If you wan't them to stay on their side and just move down you'd need to make 2 columns.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, however I am currently not able to split the list, is there a css trick that you know of to seperate them?

Comment: With CSS, no... you'd have to either render it server-side or use javascript to manipulate the items into separate lists.

Comment: Even if you use `column-count: 2` you will still get a glitchy like animation that will push the `li`s that are underneath into the next column. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/S89Uv/4/

Comment: Im currently trying styling the list as a css table, trying to get just the cell to expand on click

Comment: This would be an okay option to separate each one from another but I don't think what you want will happen without splitting them up into two `ul`s. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/S89Uv/5/

Comment: ya ive almost given up hope.., thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit with this in your jsfiddle and came up with some jQuery code that splits your existing HTML into 2 lists and looks like it behaves how you want it. I updated the CSS accordingly.  Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/S89Uv/7/

jQuery Code to split your list:

```
var everyOtherLi = $('ul.main li:odd');
var firstColumnList = $('ul.main');
var secondColumnList = $('<ul class="main"></ul>').insertAfter(firstColumnList);
secondColumnList.append(everyOtherLi);
```